# NoSuchElementException - не получается нажать кнопку

Tags: python, selenium

Делаю бота, принимающего текст и выдающего картинку, сгенерированную по этому тексту.
Нужно вписать текст в спец.поле и нажать кнопку "Run". Поле текста он находит спокойно, а при попытке нажать на кнопку происходит следующее:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".mud-button-root mud-button mud-button-filled mud-button-filled-success mud-button-filled-size-medium mud-ripple"}
```

Пробовал и переключаться на другие фреймы, и искать по другим параметрам - все тщетно.
Интересно, что со вводом текста была та же самая проблема - помог поиск не по классу, а по XPath.

Код привожу ниже:

```
driver = webdriver.Edge()
driver.get('https://dezgo.com')
driver.maximize_window()
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/textarea")))

element.send_keys('test')

button = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "mud-button-root mud-button mud-button-filled mud-button-filled-success mud-button-filled-size-medium mud-ripple").click
```